# Wrapping page-width-exceeding tables in Pandoc (docx->pdf)

Tags: pdf, latex, markdown, docx, pandoc

I'm trying to convert a rather long docx file to a pdf via pandoc, and was wondering if there's any way that I can get pandoc to automatically use multi-line tables in the output pdf. I know that there's a pandoc multiline table markdown extension, so would there be anyway to convert a docx file into a multiline-markdown-compliant format, or just convert it like this to a pdf directly?

Comment: "multi-line tables" describes how you format the input markdown, this doesn't apply if you import from docx. What exact issue are you encountering with your tables? (screenshots?)

Answer (score 0):

On Windows you would normally print the DOCX to a PDF printer.
That is the easiest and most precise way to convert from DOCX to PDF.

I wanted to have RST as the main format.
Therefore I converted some DOCX to restructuredText (RST) with pandoc.

Table entries were sometimes made multi-line, where they were not,
breaking words.

I converted them to list-table with this script: [listtable.py](https://gist.github.com/rpuntaie/c23c1b6af41055df9482f1eecd1a70d9)
(0 in the `join` param string brings together lines in that position=column without space)

From RST to HTML, PDF, DOCX I use this script:
[dcx.py](https://gist.github.com/rpuntaie/58e1b222531146a7491451916fc2bb0c)

In the Makefile you will see the pandoc command to convert to pdf.

I doubt, a direct conversion using pandoc would bring good results. 
Use an intermediate (light) markup text format and edit that until the conversion to pdf fits your expectations. 
This makes only sense if you want a pure text version anyway.